# Bootstrap and custom css top boxez

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to make collapsible top boxes. but somehow I was not successful. I want to make objects such as cards on the links page materialize. but also bootstrap
card subject at this link: materializecss.com/cards.html

[image]
[image]

```css
.card3 {
    padding: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 97.5%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    border-radius: 4px;
    height: 92%;
    z-index: 1; 
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
             <div id="card3" class="card3">   
                .......          
             </div> 
            <div class="panel panel-default">  
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        ......
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        .......
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi this might help --> https://jsfiddle.net/8be3kfmu/ <---

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried styling the other divs? Because right now only one of the divs has styling, and that usually doesn't end up with a properly styled product.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
 .container
{
  background:gray;
  padding: 20px;
 }
.col-md-12 {
    padding: 10px;

    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 97.5%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    border-radius: 4px;
    height: 12%;
    z-index: 1; 
    overflow: hidden;

}
.wrong
{
  float:right;
  top:0px;
  margin-top:-70px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/roum8xfd/3/)